# Longest stack-sortable subsequence

Tags: ds.algorithms, dynamic-programming

Given an array of $n$ pairwise-different positive integers, the problem is to find the longest subsequence that is [stack-sortable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-sortable_permutation), i.e. avoiding the permutation pattern $231$.

How fast can this problem be solved? Can it be solved in polynomial time and linear space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a polynomial-time dynamic programming algorithm in section 3.2 of https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/28/ajc_v28_p225.pdf (Albert et al, "Longest subsequences in permutations", *Australas. J. Combin.* 28 (2003), 225–238)